# Magento 2.4.6 at checkout page for pin code changes the AJAX call to "estimate-shipping-methods" does not trigger

Tags: magento2

Could anyone help to solve the matter ->  in magento 2.4.6 at checkout page for pincode changes and if the custom shipping method is enable the AJAX call to "estimate-shipping-methods" does not trigger.

Comment: check console is there any error?